# React Redux not working after migrating class component to functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an ExportBtn component that fetches and exports data to an excel file on click. The following class component works:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {LoaderBtn, createReport} from './utils.js';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {actions} from './actions.js'

class ExportBtn extends Component {
  btn = null;

  componentDidMount(){
    this.btn = LoaderBtn.create(document.querySelector('#exportBtn'));
  }

  exportTable(){
    this.btn.start();
    this.props.fetchReportData(this.props.searchParams).then(() => {
      this.btn.stop();
      createReport(this.props.exportedResults)
    });
  }

  reunder(){
    return (
      <button 
        id="exportBtn"
        onClick={this.exportTable}
        >{'Export'}</button>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    exportedResults: state.exportedResults
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchReportData: actions.fetchReportData
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExportBtn);
```

Now, I'm migrating to functional components and I came out with the following code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { LoaderBtn, createReport } from './utils.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { actions } from './actions.js';

function ExportBtn(props) {
  const btnRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    btnRef.current = LoaderBtn.create(document.querySelector('#exportBtn'));
  }, []);

  function exportTable() {
    btnRef.current.start();
    props.fetchReportData(props.searchParams).then(() => {
      btnRef.current.stop();
      createReport(props.exportedResults);
    });
  }

  return (
    <button
      id="exportBtn"
      onClick={exportTable}
    >
      Export
    </button>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    exportedResults: state.exportedResults
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchReportData: actions.fetchReportData
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ExportBtn);
```

And now, `props.exportedResults` is null the first time I click the button. Which kinda makes sense, because when it was clicked the redux state wasn't populated. However, using the class component snippet, it works.

Am I falling in a redux anti-pattern or am I missing something?

I expected props.exportedResults to be populated after calling the fetchReportData function

Comment: There's no context of what these props are supposed to be, but if you don't want `createReport` to call when `props.exportedResults` is `null` you can create guards checks like `if (props.exportedResults !== null) {...}`

Comment: And you don't need those `mapStateToProps` .. `connect` methods, they were used **5** years ago in class based components, you rather watch YouTube video on Redux and clean the messiness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is `props.exportedResults` is changed when you do `props.fetchReportData`. So, might seem it's using an **old** value of `props.exportedResults` when you are using the **then** in the promise resolution.

So, I can make you a couple of comments. Although **connect** is fine, and it works, it's like "recommended" to use **React hooks** when you enter a functional approach.

**React-Redux** hooks for a functional approach are `useDispatch` and `useState`. I'd recommend you using these.

But if you still want to use **connect** and this is ok, I'd investigate if you can access "fresh" props on the promise resolution for the **dispatch**. That will make your code work.